# How to crop an image and save a copy in the database on upload with MERN

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload, mern

I currently have a webpage where users can upload images and the images get saved to a mongodb database. I used the code from [This Tutorial](https://codeburst.io/image-uploading-using-react-and-node-to-get-the-images-up-c46ec11a7129) for the basic image uploading. I want the program to make a copy of the image, crop a square out of the center and save the copy to the database. How would I do that?

Comment: I know this isn't React, but have you thought of doing something like this where you have the user crop the image prior to sending it to your API? https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2019/06/image-cropping-zooming-scaling-angular-javascript/

Comment: As long as I can force them to crop a square and there's a good react tutorial I would be happy with that

Comment: I created the same tutorial in React for you: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2020/02/scale-crop-zoom-images-react-web-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using node module called sharp.
You may go through [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)